# gdb remote kernel debugging adds bug

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, gdb

I am debugging linux-kernel using two virtual machines, a host and target. Connected via serial port `/dev/ttyS0`.

---

**HOST**
The command lines are highlighted with `--> <--`

```
--> root@tony-VirtualBox:~/linux# gdb ./vmlinux <--

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./vmlinux...done.

--> (gdb) target remote /dev/ttyS0 <--

Remote debugging using /dev/ttyS0
0xc1119026 in free_rp_inst (rp=<optimized out>)
    at kernel/kprobes.c:1248
1248            kfree(ri);
(gdb) break htb_dequeue_tree
Breakpoint 1 at 0xc17165a9: file net/sched/sch_htb.c, line 850.
(gdb) continue
continuing.
```

From this point I am connected to the target machine, I insert breakpoints at interesting points and then `continue` to start it the target machine. Control will return when I hit that breakpoint ([HTB](http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm) is a module that helps controlling the use of the outbound bandwidth on a given link).

---

**Target**

Using [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) to test linux htb

```
tc qdisc add dev eno2 root handle 1: htb 
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100kbps ceil 100kbps
tc class add dev eno2 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 30kbps ceil 100kbps
tc class add dev eno2 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 10kbps ceil 100kbps
tc filter add dev eno2 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 80 0xffff flowid 1:10
tc filter add dev eno2 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 25 0xffff flowid 1:20
```

---

**Problem**

When I start server and connect to it, in-order to hit that breakpoint, I am receiving `SIGILL` before that breakpoint is reached. Without debugging mode, it works perfectly. And I am able to test HTB and am getting what I am expecting (Shaping the traffic the way I intended).

```
[New Thread -2]

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
[Switching to Thread -2]
0xc17165a8 in ffz (word=3889660160)
    at ./arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h:381
381                    : "r" (~word));

(gdb)
```

What could it possibly be? here is where [ffz](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h.html#372) is defined, it shouldn't crash... I am confused.

Comment: Which instruction at 0xc17165a8 address in vmlinux do you have?
Which virtual machines do you use?

Comment: @Jettatura if I do x 0xc171765a8 I get `htb_dequeue:295` a line that does not exist in this function.

Comment: Could you try `disassemble` command at gdb?  What kind of illegal instruction exception: is it broken stack, and return from function cause invalid instruction, or maybe there was not enable some x86_64 ISA feature, that ffz use, or you virtual machine do not implement it (what is it, by the way?). 
Try to find what instruction was compiled for that address  `objdump -D vmlinux | grep 171765a8` if it present at kernel proper. Try to find encoding of instruction that cause illegal exception ( by `disasm' cmd at gdb) at  x86 ISA reference manual, check CPUID flags, check previous instructions

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the rodata=off and nokaslr kernel boot parameters.

Here is how to add kernel boot parameters:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter